# Is there a way to make restriction on multiple elements in xsd schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I was doing xsd schema and I was thinking is there a way to make restriction for multiple elements and not only for one at a time. I want to do this so I can make the schema more readable.This is my schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com"
       elementFormDefault="qualified"
       xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com">
<xs:element name="WorldWideHappiness" type="worldHappiness"/>
<xs:complexType name="worldHappiness">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="Record" type="recordType" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="recordType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Country" type="countryType" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="countryType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="Region" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="HappinessRank">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="HappinessScore">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
                <xs:minInclusive value="0.0"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="LowerConfidenceInterval">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="0.0"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="UpperConfidenceInterval">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="0.0"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="Health">

            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="0.0"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>

    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType></xs:schema>
```

I want to know if I can give minInclusive for all of the simple types which has minInclusive 0.0 and not individually.

Comment: We need a minimal reproducible example from you. Please edit your question and add XML sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your own common simple type, and use where applicable.
Any change to that simple type in one single spot will apply to all elements that are using it.

Please see below a conceptual example.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <HappinessScore>0.1</HappinessScore>
    <LowerConfidenceInterval>0.75</LowerConfidenceInterval>
    <Health>770</Health>
</root>
```

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="HappinessScore" type="decimalType"/>
                <xs:element name="LowerConfidenceInterval" type="decimalType"/>
                <xs:element name="Health" type="decimalType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="decimalType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
            <xs:minInclusive value="0.0"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: @ Yitzhak Khabinsky I have to ask, is this wrong to do, regarding the rules ? Is it better just to make restrictions individually ?

Comment: @GEORGIDIMITROV, it is perfectly fine as long as the same rules are applicable to elements.